# argumento padrão em função javascript

Tags: javascript

Qual dessas, ou outra, é a melhor forma de setar valor padrão de uma função javascript?

```
function func(arg){
   //Esse:
   arg = arg || "valor padrão";
   //Ou esse:
   if(arg === void 0 ) { arg = "valor padrão"}
   //Ou esse:
   arg = arguments.length > 0 ? arguments[0] : "valor padrão";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O citado já [parâmetro padrão (parâmetro por defeito/Default parameters)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) é uma boa saída:

```js
function foo(bar = 1) {
     console.log(bar);
}

foo();
foo('oi');
```

No entanto o que ninguém citou ainda é que isto **não vai funcionar em navegadores mais antigos**, como:

- Internet Explorer (mesmo no 11)
- Safari 9 (ou mais antigo)

E provavelmente não vai funcionar em alguns navegadores Android nativos, então se a intenção é dar suporte sem querer correr riscos use o `typeof` mesmo, ou então pode usar IIEF (Immediately Invoked Function Expression), assim:

```js
/*
w = window
d = document
u = undefined
*/
(function (w, d, u) {
    w.minhaFuncao = function (a, b, c) {
          a = a === u ? 'valor padrão para "a"' : a;
          b = b === u ? 'valor padrão para "b"' : b;
          c = c === u ? 'valor padrão para "c"' : c;
          
          console.log('/a => ', a, '/b => ', b, '/c => ', c);
    };

    w.minhaOutraFuncao = function (foo, bar) {
          foo = foo === u ? 1 : foo;
          bar = bar === u ? 1 : bar;
          
          console.log('/foo => ', foo, '/bar => ', bar);
    };
})(window, document);

minhaFuncao();
minhaFuncao('A');
minhaFuncao('A', 'B');
minhaFuncao('A', 'B', 'C');

minhaOutraFuncao();
minhaOutraFuncao('FOO');
minhaOutraFuncao('FOO', 'BAR');
```

Comment: @sam o critério foi tentar evitar o imediatismo que já tinha ocorrido com respostas `usa X`, `usa Y`, sem haver qualquer analise sobre quando deve se usar algo, a ideia aqui é tentar concertar as coisas dentro do problema especifico que outras respostas podem causar, o correto nem era ninguém ter respondido, era terem votado para fechar, mas como é comum na comunidade só alguns se darem ao trabalho de votar, então me vejo obrigado a formular uma resposta para apontar possiveis problemas das soluções propostas [...]

Comment: [...] não é que as respostas sejam problematicas inteiramente, mas falta explicar o quando usar, ai o AP sai usando algo que não foi explicado a parte de compatibilidade e seus scripts começam a falhar pois por um acaso os clientes dele usam androids antigos ou IE. Ou seja ele vai ter muita dor de cabeça por falta de citarem isto que é muito importante ;) ps: Só pra constar, isso não é um "critério", é uma situação IMPAR, ou seja cada pergunta tem que ser analisada e respostas dadas também :)

Comment: Entendi agora o critério. Mt bom.

Answer (score 1):

Na realidade seria assim:

```
function func(parametro = 'valor padrão') {

}
```

Não é muito bom usar `arg` ou `args` como nome de parâmetro também.

Answer (score 1):

Por segurança, acho melhor você informar no construtor do método.

O exemplo `arg = arg || "valor padrão";` geraria uma instabilidade caso o tipo do parâmetro fosse boolean ou então um numérico, "caso você informasse false ou 0, ele iria assumir um valor padrão".

Você pode estar usando o typeof ou então estar declarando no construtor do método, segue exemplos abaixo:

> No construtor do método (eu recomendo):

```
function teste(param = 'valor padrão') {
     console.log(param);
}

teste(); // imprime a string valor padrão no console.
teste('oi'); // imprime a string oi no console.
```

> Usando o typeof:

```
function teste(param) {
     if(typeof param === 'undefined') {
          param = 'valor padrão';
     }
     console.log(param);
}

teste(); // imprime a string valor padrão no console.
teste('oi'); // imprime a string oi no console.
```